# C# specified time label change the structure

Tags: c#

```
int sn = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Konfigürasyon Yükleniyor.";
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sn == 3)
    {
        label1.Text = "Ayarlar Alınıyor";
    }
    if (sn == 5)
    {
        label1.Text = "Program Başlatılıyor";
    }
    sn++;
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

When I open the form I want to change the label when I select the text range.

Comment: Not clear. You are stopping the timer the first time it expires....

Comment: Did you add the timer's eventhandler?

Comment: no,eventhandler section How do I add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that event handler is attached in designer to this `timer1`.

As far as I can understand, this label is never set, because you stop Timer after it hits first time.

In  this case variable `sn = 0` so non of `if` condition from your event handler is met.

I think to solve problem you sould remove this `timer1.Stop()` from event handler.

Comment: thank you guys, remove this timer1.stop(); problem solved

Comment: @RobbaN: I'd rather *stopped* the timer if it's not needed any more, but I would do it after the 5th second

Comment: @RobbaN: Further if you don't stop the timer and it runs continoulsy on the flag `sn` will be increased all the time. So if the programm is active a long long time a buffer overflow could happen. So the proper way is to stop the timer as Dmitry suggested.

Comment: That's right, but it can be stopped anywhere in this form actually. Maybe other part of code do this (we don't know).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sn == 3)
      label1.Text = "Ayarlar Alınıyor";
    else if (sn == 5) {
      label1.Text = "Program Başlatılıyor";

      timer1.Stop(); // <- stop timer here on the 5th second, not on the 1st one
    }

    sn++;
  }
```